# difference between normal execution of glm.nb and geom_smooth execution of glm.nb for a spline model

Tags: r, ggplot2, glm, spline

I'm trying to fit a negative binomial glm for two different conditions to my data.
first, some toy data :

```
    value      times variable
1   82.21236  0.0000000        B
2  130.69185  0.0000000        A
3  159.10491  1.3131313        B
4  136.94357  0.6060606        A
5  192.22455  3.1313131        B
6  149.96539  3.1313131        A
7  115.91152  4.5454545        B
8   95.26077  4.2424242        A
9   73.79734  6.2626263        B
10  71.43359  6.1616162        A
11 106.83029  7.4747475        B
12 134.01414  7.0707071        A
13  44.66716  8.6868687        B
14  57.47017  8.6868687        A
15  41.02301  9.8989899        B
16  42.47003  9.4949495        A
17  66.26286  0.0000000        B
18 122.70818  0.0000000        A
19 187.01966  1.6161616        B
20 199.92595  1.6161616        A
21 138.26999  2.9292929        B
22  94.63155  3.2323232        A
23 149.99105  4.5454545        B
24 121.49791  4.1414141        A
25 107.17931  5.6565657        B
26  91.04130  5.7575758        A
27  84.03087  7.7777778        B
28  62.17754  7.6767677        A
29  52.81123  8.9898990        B
30  72.61422  7.5757576        A
31  52.33281 10.0000000        B
32  39.60495  9.6969697        A
```

(the libraries :
library(ggplot2)
library(MASS)
)

My aim is to retrieve the model that is fit to my data for downstream analysis, no just to visualize it, so i first went for the glm.nb function of the MASS package, but it fails to fit the data and I don't know why, especially since the same method succeeds with ggplot.
here is the code i've used so far :

```
ans = glm.nb(data = data,  formula = value~splines::bs(times,Boundary.knots = c(0,10), knots = c(3), degree = 3, intercept = F ):variable)
data$glm_nb = predict(ans) #make the glm model and predict the new values

p=ggplot(data, aes(x=times, y=value, group=variable)) + #plot it 
  facet_grid(.~variable)+theme_bw() +
   theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank())+
         labs(x="times",y="Value")+
         geom_point(size=2,alpha = 0.2) + theme_bw(base_size = 22)+
         stat_smooth(method = "glm.nb", formula = y~splines::bs(x,Boundary.knots = c(0,10), knots = c(3), degree = 3, intercept = F), color = "green", size = 0.3)+ #ggplot with the same model
         geom_line(aes(x = times, y = glm_nb), color = "blue")
```

both models, the ggplot and the other ones, give warnings that my x values are no integers, but ggplot still succeeds to fit the data.
[image]

What is especially wierd is that when I try to use a GLM, it actually works ! (same code, just swapped glm.nb for glm).
[image]
I tried to look up the source code to see what does geom_smooth exactly do, but i couldn't find the precise line where it calculates its models.
Any ideas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is simply that you are getting the wrong values out of your `predict` call, because by default it sets the return type to `type = "link"`, whereas you are looking for `type = "response"`. If you make this change, you get identical results to `ggplot`, which knows to use `type = "response"` without being asked:

```r
data$glm_nb <- predict(ans, type = "response")

ggplot(data, aes(x = times, y = value, group = variable)) +
  geom_point(size=2,alpha = 0.2) +
  stat_smooth(method = "glm.nb", 
              formula = y ~ splines::bs(x, Boundary.knots = c(0,10), 
                                        knots = c(3), degree = 3, 
                                        intercept = FALSE), 
              color = "green", size = 0.3) +
  geom_line(aes(x = times, y = glm_nb), color = "blue") +
  facet_grid(.~variable) +
  labs(x = "times", y = "Value") +
  theme_bw(base_size = 22)
```

[image]

Comment: thanks ! Am feeling a bit stupid not to have checked for that...

Comment: @Tkastylevsky not at all. I only know this because I have also made this mistake many times!